# Custom Xml Serializer for a specific type in asp.net web api

Tags: serialization, xml-serialization, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I am in asp.net web api. In an API method, I am calling an external web service, that returns XML response. I don't want to deserialize it. I would rather like to send it to the client as is. Initially, I am storing the response in `XDocument` object but when my client specifies `application/xml` as accept header, I see the following exception

```
Type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDeclaration' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute. See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
```

How do I get around this problem

Comment: Could you share how your api method looks like? From the description above i think your object is being trying to be serialized by a formatter which you are not looking for...so would like to see the api method...

Answer (score 3):

Great Q,i simple write your problem use in api member:

```
 [HttpGet]
 [ActionName("Books")]
 public HttpResponseMessage MyBook()
    {
        var request = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<books><book><author>MS</author><name>ASP.NET</name></book></books>");
        request.Content = new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");

        return request;
    }
```

Try this member source.

Comment: I think it would work (not tried) but it wouldn't allow for content negotiation to work. i.e if user specifies `application/json` in accept header, it would still send xml response, no?

Comment: Change to Content `request.Content = new StringContent(doc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`  Headers in Content Type 'application/json'

Comment: Or try test  this Api member in JS:`$.ajax({
        url: 'api/Membership/JsonTest',
        type: 'GET',
        data: null,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("There was an error posting the data to the server: " + error.responseText);
        }
    });`

Comment: Ok, this solution can be used for time being but Ideally, I would not like to play with content negotiation in API methods